# Endienness conversion between Little and Big

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

does java have a function to make a direct conversion between Little and BigEndien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several. Byte order can be swapped using ByteBuffer or Integer/Long.reverseBytes